# How to get current number of viewers for specific live video with YouTube API?

Tags: json, video, youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming

How to get current number of viewers for live video with YouTube API?

I can see number of current viewers using request for feed of videos like this: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/live/events/live_now?v=2&alt=json&inline=true&max-results=20&start-index=1

It returns me random videos, but I need to get current viewers for specific video. So when I using request for video ( like this https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fWuS8hM_5D8?v=2&alt=json ) there is no currentViewers field, onlie viewCount.

Is there any solution of this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now possible with V3 of the YouTube API ... you request the videos object, passing in the videoID that represents the live stream, and ask for the "liveStreamingDetails" part. One of the parameters returned will be "concurrentViewers" -- for more info:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers

Answer (score 9):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id={YT ID}&fields=items%2FliveStreamingDetails%2FconcurrentViewers&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You must get unique google api key (at first read here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started ). After you can get any metrics (more read here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers ). In my example i getting just one metric (concurrentViewers) where {YT ID} - youtube video id and {YOUR_API_KEY} - your api key.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at this time. This kind of public informations are not share with the API YouTube.

From the @Jeff Posnick [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12982574/2274530) :

> Unfortunately, while that data is available in a backend that the
>   YouTube web interface can access, it's not exposed at all via any API
>   (YT Data API v1/v2/v3 or YT Analytics API) at this time.

Comment: I saw this answer, but it was two years ago... So situation has not changed, it's sad.