# Loading YouTube Number of People Watching Live into Span using jQuery Updating every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I want to take the information found here:

https://www.youtube.com/live_stats?v=uSajGtd5SnY

Which returns a number that is displayed on the page.

I want to take that and put it into a span with the id of "live-watching".

I want this to be automatically updated every 5 seconds.

Dont really know where to even begin because I'm new to jQuery. I've been looking but I can't seem to piece the things i want together.

Heres a code pen for the set up, where X should be updated every 5 seconds with the number of people watching live:

https://codepen.io/JDSWebService/pen/yXLjdK

```
 <p>Number of People Watching <span id="live-watching">X</span></p>
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I'm very unfamiliar with working with jQuery, and YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start an ajax call, then update the number on success and repeat after 5 seconds ( with jquery) :

```
(function reload(){
$.ajax({
  url:"https://www.youtube.com/live_stats?v=uSajGtd5SnY",
  success:function(data){
     $("#live-watching").html(data);
     setTimeout(reload,5000);
  }
});
})();
```

Note that ajax calls to another domain may be blocked. In this case, you need to use a youtube api instead...

Comment: This doesn't work. Unfortunately you have to use the API.

Comment: @J. Robinson well, then grab an api key at http://console.developers.google.com and find out the related api call, and replace the url above with this url...

Comment: @J. Robinson oh i just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961137/grabbing-the-current-viewer-count-for-youtube-live-streams ... Does not look good...